# How to design indexes for columns with NULL values in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, index

I have a database with 40 million entries and want to run queries with the following `WHERE` clause

```
...
WHERE
  `POP1` IS NOT NULL 
  && `VT`='ABC'
  && (`SOURCE`='HOME')
  && (`alt` RLIKE '^[AaCcGgTt]$')
  && (`ref` RLIKE '^[AaCcGgTt]$')
  && (`AA` RLIKE '^[AaCcGgTt]$')
  && (`ref` = `AA` || `alt` = `AA`)
LIMIT 10 ;
```

`POP1` is a float column that can also be NULL. `POP1 IS NOT NULL` should exclude about 50% of the entries, that's why I put it at the beginning. All other terms reduce the number only marginally.

Amongst others, I designed an index `pop1_vt_source`, which seems to be not used, while an index with `vt` as first column is used. EXPLAIN-output:

```
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                          | key                 | key_len | ref         | rows     | Extra       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | myTab | ref  | vt_source_pop1_pop2,pop1_vt_source,... | vt_source_pop1_pop2 | 206     | const,const | 20040021 | Using where |
```

Why is the index with `pop1` as the first column not used? Because of the `NOT` or because of `NULL` in general. How can I improve the design of my indices and WHERE clauses? Even when limiting to 10 entries, the query takes more than 30 seconds, although the first 100 entries in the table should contain the 10 matches.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is the `NOT NULL`:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `myTab` (`notnul` FLOAT, `nul` FLOAT);
INSERT INTO `myTab` VALUES (1, NULL), (1, 2), (1, NULL), (1, 2), (1, NULL), (1, 2), (1, NULL), (1, 2), (1, NULL), (1, 2), (1, NULL), (1, 2);
SELECT * FROM `myTab`;
```

gives:

```
+--------+------+
| notnul | nul  |
+--------+------+
|      1 | NULL |
|      1 |    2 |
|      1 | NULL |
|      1 |    2 |
|      1 | NULL |
|      1 |    2 |
|      1 | NULL |
|      1 |    2 |
|      1 | NULL |
|      1 |    2 |
|      1 | NULL |
|      1 |    2 |
+--------+------+
```

Create the index:

```
CREATE INDEX `notnul_nul` ON `myTab` (`notnul`, `nul`);
CREATE INDEX `nul_notnul` ON `myTab` (`nul`, `notnul`);

SHOW INDEX FROM `myTab`;
```

gives:

```
+-------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name   | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| myTab |          1 | notnul_nul |            1 | notnul      | A         |          12 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| myTab |          1 | notnul_nul |            2 | nul         | A         |          12 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| myTab |          1 | nul_notnul |            1 | nul         | A         |          12 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| myTab |          1 | nul_notnul |            2 | notnul      | A         |          12 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

now explain the selects.
It seems that MySQL uses the index, even if You use `NOT NULL`:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `myTab` WHERE `notnul` IS NOT NULL;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+ 
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+ 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | myTab | index | notnul_nul    | notnul_nul | 10      | NULL |   12 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+


EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `myTab` WHERE `nul` IS NOT NULL;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | myTab | range | nul_notnul    | nul_notnul | 5       | NULL |    6 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
```

But, when comparing `NOT NULL` and `NULL`, it seems that MySQL preferrs other indexes when using `NOT NULL`. Although this does obviously not add any information. This is because MySQL interprets `NOT NULL` as a range as you can see in type-column. I'm not sure If there is a workaround:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `myTab` WHERE `nul` IS NULL && notnul=2;
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys         | key        | key_len | ref         | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | myTab | ref  | notnul_nul,nul_notnul | notnul_nul | 10      | const,const |    1 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------+--------------------------+


EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `myTab` WHERE `nul` IS NOT NULL && notnul=2;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-----------------------+------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys         | key        | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-----------------------+------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | myTab | range | notnul_nul,nul_notnul | notnul_nul | 10      | NULL |    1 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-----------------------+------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
```

I think there could be a better implementation in MySQL, because `NULL` is a special value. Probably most people are interested in `NOT NULL` values.

Answer (score 3):

The issue isn't the NULL values.  It is the selectivity of the index.  In your example, the selectivity of `source, pop1` is better than the selectivity of just `pop1`.  It covers more of the conditions in the `where` clause, so it is more likely to reduce page hits.

You may think that reducing the number of rows by 50% is enough, but it really isn't.  The benefit of indexes in a `where` clause is to reduce the number of pages being read.  If a page has, on average, at least one record with a non-NULL value, then there is no gain to using the index.  And, if there are 10 records per page, then almost every page will have one of those records.

You might try an index on `(pop1, vt, source)`.  The optimizer should pick that one up.

In the end, though, if the `where` clause is keeping lost of records -- there is not rule but let's say 20% -- then the index probably won't help.  One exception would be when the index contains *all* the columns needed by the query.  Then it can satisfy the query without bringing in the data page for each record.

And, if an index gets used and the selectivity is high, then performance with the index could be worse than performance without it.

Comment: I think it really is the ranges that causes the difference (see my answer). Although I think it could be better implemented in MySQL, since most people are interested in `NOT NULL` columns.